# Using java to get the URL from the web browser's active tab

Tags: java, google-chrome

I am trying to write Java code to get the URL from Chrome's active tab via getter and listener, but my getter always outputs "about:blank" and my listener never gets triggered.

For the getter, I am using the getURL method in org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.

For the listener, I am creating a listener class that extends the org.eclipse.swt.browser.LocationAdapter interface.

Am I on the right path, or is the chrome browser data in a different class library?

Comment: Have you started Chrome from the Browser class? I don't think you can get the URL of an "external" browser. (Say I have started Safari, Firefox and Chrome and have two windows of each open. What would getUrl then return?

Comment: I am not sure if Chrome can be started from the Browser class or what getURL would return, but my code needs a getter and listener which returns the URL of the active tab of the internet browser which is being viewed.  If no browser is being viewed at the time, the getter/listener performs no action.  Does any Java class provide this option?  I have searched Stackoverflow and can not find the answer to this question.

Comment: @RogerLindsjo:  Can you please tell me how to start Chrome from the Browser class?  I searched stackoverflow and did not find any instructions on how to do this.